# How do I test whether two events are independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I'm trying to understand how to mathematically determine whether two events are independent. This is for introduction to statistics, so the solution and explanation to this is likely very simple, yet there's something I'm not understanding.

---

**Here's the question from my textbook:**

> A statistical experiment has 11 equally likely outcomes that are
> denoted by a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k.
>
> Event A = {b, d, e, j}
>
> Event B = {a, c, f, j}

---

If two events, A and B, are independent, then $P(A) = P(A|B)$. Therefore if I want to determine whether the two events are independent, I need to solve for $P(A)$ and $P(A|B)$ to check whether they are equal.

However $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}$, and this is where I get stuck, because I can't know which multiplication rule to use to figure out $P(A∩B)$ since I don't yet know whether the events are independent or not?

If the events are independent, then $P(A∩B) = P(A) * P(B)$. Otherwise if they are dependent, then $P(A∩B) = P(A) * P(B|A)$.

I know that I can solve the question from my textbook by looking at the outcomes that intersect between the two events, but is it possible to figure out whether the two events are independent solely by using the formulae above?

Comment: I think you need to tell us *something* about the events themselves?

Comment: @311411, I've updated my post with more details.

Comment: Computation of $~p(A \cap B)~$ does not (normally) require knowledge of whether $~A~$ and $~B~$ are independent events.  That is, the probability of both events occurring simultaneously can usually be done without analyzing the extent that one event's occurrence affects whether the other event occurs.

Comment: $P(A\cap B) = P(A) \times  P(B\mid A)$ is true, whether or not $A$ and $B$ are independent. $P(A\cap B) = P(A) \times  P(B)$ is true if and only if they are independent.

Comment: @Henry, sure, but then how do I calculate P(B|A)? I'd get stuck in a loop again unless I already know P(B|A) or P(A and B).

Comment: @user928112 You can see from your original question that clearly $P(A \text{ and } B)=\frac1{11}$ and that almost as clearly $P(B \mid A)=\frac1{4}$, based on $|\{j\}|=1$ and "equally likely"

Comment: @Henry, in this example, yes both are clearly known. However my question is a hypothetical one: could we determine interdependency if we only had P(A) and P(B) with and nothing else? Some of the other users have already stated that this would be impossible to do without trial and error.

Comment: Is this too simple, or is 'two' events far too few to make any test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case $P(A)=4/11$, $P(B)=4/11$ and $A\cap B={j}$, $P(A \cap B)=1/11$. Now you can see whether A and B are independent.

Comment: Got it now. I was overthinking this and the solution seems to be simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You figure out the independence of the events based on what they produce from the equations. If P(A∩B)=P(A)∗P(B) then the events are independent. If you have P(A) and are missing both P(A∩B) and P(B) then you don't have enough information to answer if the events are independent or not. Basically you need to have enough information to determine independency.

Comment: I have P(A) and P(B) but I am missing P(A∩B). I cannot calculate P(A∩B) on my own because that requires knowledge of whether the events are dependent or independent (which is what I am trying to figure out in the first place). Essentially, I can try P(A)∗P(B), but would have no idea whether the result is correct because that multiplication rule only applies to independent events.

Comment: Well you just don't know other than based on the physical event that is happening. For example if a coin is flipped fairly then you use the independent equations. If the coin depends somehow on what happened previously then you need to know how it depends on that.

Comment: kmitov has showed you how to find P(A and B)

Comment: Sorry I had commented and answered based on when the question had less information, refer to kmitov's answer for information about the specific problem

Comment: @Conor_Meise, I saw kmitov's solution to my specific problem, but you also answered a secondary question that I had around whether or not it's at all possible to figure out interdependency without knowledge of the physical event, and without prior knowledge of P(A and B). Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

> **Here's the question from my textbook:**
>
> > A statistical experiment has *11 equally likely outcomes* that are denoted by a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k.
> >
> > Event A = {b, d, e, j}
> >
> > Event B = {a, c, f, j}

Therefore $A\cap B = \{j\}$ and ...

Comment: And how would you determine P(A and B) if you had been given just P(A), P(B), and nothing else? Judging by Conor's comments, it seems that we wouldn't be able to do that. For one, we wouldn't know which multiplication rule to use since that itself requires prior knowledge on whether the events are dependent or not. That's mainly what I was hung up on rather than just the textbook question itself.

Comment: Take the intersection of $A$ and $B$ as sets. That is the very definition of $A \cap B$.